# Script to Reload specific Web App

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, ant

### **Hello internet,**

**I have been looking for the past two hours for a script to reload my web app.**

- I'm using Tomcat on a windows server 2003.
- I know that there is a link to reload
  your web app, but i'm wondering if i
  can automate the process to reload my
  web app once every 8 hours.

I would really appreciate if you could give me hint or two :)

---

Thank you in advance

Comment: (sounds like hiding memory leaks or stability issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler to do this.

It looks like tomcat is installed as windows service so you can create a batch (.bat) file to stop and start the service. It should look something like this:

```
net stop tomcat
net start tomcat
```

Just setup the scheduled task to run this batch file every 8 hours.

Comment: The service name 'tomcat' may have the version number in it such as 'tomcat6' so you'll need to check that:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

there are two original batch to start tomcat, i just plan them to execute every 8 hours. 
As easy as that.